# Unit test for method with Closeable parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, interface, junit

I am new to unit testing.

How should I write a JUnit test for this method?

```
public static void close(Closeable closeable) {
        if (closeable == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            closeable.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: By mocking a closeable?

Comment: And you don't even need to use a fancy mocking library like Mockito. You can do it yourself by creating a class that implements `Closeable` and has a `boolean isClosed` field that you set to `true` on `close()`, and then can check from your test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
@Test
public void nominalClose() {
    Closeable closeable = new MyCloseable();
    Assert.assertFalse(closeable.isClosed());
    MyClass.close(closeable);    // call to the method you want to test
    Assert.assertTrue(closeable.isClosed());
}

@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class) 
public void ioExceptionClose() {
    Closeable closeable = new Closeable(){
        @Override
        public void close() {
            throw new IOException("test IO");
        }
    };
    MyClass.close(closeable);    // call should send a RuntimeException
}

// TODO: add more tests? Null? not IOException?

private static class MyCloseable implements Closeable {
    private boolean closed = false;
    @Overrive
    public void close() {
        closed = true;
    }
    public boolean isClosed() {
        return closed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the case where you pass null into MyClass.close() and this is perfect.

Comment: Yes, other tests might be added, I just wanted to show the main ones.

Comment: Yep, you got my +1, awesome answer!